# CSS arrow from menu to submenu

Tags: css, menu

I am fairly new to CSS and have been learning mostly by copying and pasting and slowly making customizations.I was wondering about how to create and arrow from your menu to submenu categories.

I have tried some other questions and forums but they do now help me get the result I would like. Hope someone is able to help out the newbie!!

PS.
Sorry to those who thought that my question was spam, I removed the link and will just see what comes up in comments! :)

Comment: It would have been better to post a link to an image of what you want rather than the site. Your post is being flagged as spam.

Comment: @ChrisF oh no thats not what I meant at all :( I can change it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

## ***HTML***

> You can make them with a single div. It's nice to have classes for each direction possibility.

```html
<div class="arrow-up"></div>
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
<div class="arrow-left"></div>
<div class="arrow-right"></div>
```

## ***CSS***

> The idea is a box with zero width and height. The actual width and height of the arrow is determined by the width of the border. In an up arrow, for example, the bottom border is colored while the left and right are transparent, which forms the triangle.

```css
.arrow-up {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;

    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.arrow-down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;

    border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}

.arrow-right {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 60px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;

    border-left: 60px solid green;
}

.arrow-left {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 

    border-right:10px solid blue; 
}
```

[image]

***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pnu25/)***

Comment: I know I probably sound stupid but where in the CSS code would I put this?

Comment: Anywhere really.  As long as your reference the correct css file in your html page, you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

You create them by using [CSS Triangles](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/), simple example, for an element like this:

```
<div id=item>Text</div>
```

The following style will add an arrow on top:

```
#item { background: #ccc; padding: 10px; position: relative; top: 10px; }
#item:before { content: ''; height: 0; position: absolute; top: -10px; width: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #ccc; }
```

[JSFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/c6x6X/)

It uses `:before` pseudo element, creating a new element on the fly and making it an arrow by the border trick.

A more complicated example, creating a full menu:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>Menu</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>sub</a>
            <li><a>menu</a>
        </ul>
    <li>
        <a>Menu</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>sub</a>
            <li><a>menu</a>
        </ul>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
a { background: #aaa; display: block; padding: 10px; width: 100px; }
li { display: inline-block; position: relative; }
li ul { display: none; }
li ul:before { content: ''; height: 0; left: 10px; position: absolute; top: -10px; width: 0; border-left: 10px solid transparent; border-right: 10px solid transparent; border-bottom: 10px solid #ccc; }
li ul a { background: #ccc; }
li:hover ul { display: block; position: absolute; top: 40px; }
ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

[JSFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/QUm96/)